# sharepoint 2007 export subsite to new site collection

Tags: 2007

We have a capacity limitation in our site collection and planning to move a fast growing subsite to a new site collection.

As microsoft recommends 100GB for a site collection, we are planning to move the subsite to a new site collection.

Can anyone suggest the recommended approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before and it can be done easily in three steps,

**Step 1: Export your subsite by using the Export-SPWeb command.**

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://someURL/SomeTeamSite/sandbox/" -Path "C:\Exported Sub Site\SandboxSubsSite.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions all
```

**Step 2: Create you site collection.  This is where you will host your new site.**

**Step 3: Import your Content Migration Package (CMP) file that you exported using Import-SPWeb.**

```
Import-SPWeb "http://someURL/sites/Sandbox" –Path "C:\Exported Sub Site\SandboxSubsSite.cmp"
```

For detailed step by step guide you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356985/Moving-a-Sharepoint-Sub-Site-to-its-own-Site-Colle)

Or you can try this free tool available on codeplex,

http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi,thanks for your quick help. How can we manage the custom solutions and workflows, already deployed on the subsite?

Answer (score 0):

TimeToThine example will not copy workflows ect but if you want it just for a simple copy than its good! and is a known issue in sharepoint... there are third party tools that address these kind of issues but none are 100%

try to do the following:

> 1. Create your new Site Collection
> 2. Restore your Site to a location in the new Site Collection
> 3. Assign a few reliable Test Users to vet the result
> 4. Tune Accordingly
>
> With the export command It is important to understand what you may NOT get as a
>   result. Exports and Imports are not technically "full fidelity",
>   meaning that things like workflows, etc. will not copy as they are
>   held within the context of the Site Collection, rather than the Site
>   itself. Other items, such as permission groups, may also be affected

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/e1ee9cba-b96a-4295-8fe2-47ca5ee27076